# Order processing in Rails - what is the best way to model this and create the associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I am having trouble with the modeling of a simple ordering system where a customer can create an order by choosing items.

The models I wanted were: Customer, Order, OrderLine and Item.
A Customer creates an Order which contains many OrderLines, with each OrderLine containing one Item with a quantity, selling_price etc. Items are "products" that a customer can choose from. Once an Item is chosen and assigned a quantity desired, an OrderLine is created.

Given that, what would be the best setup for the associations?

Here are the models in their current state:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :orders
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :order_lines
   has_many :orders, through: :order_lines
end

class OrderLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :item
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_lines
  has_many :items, through: :order_lines
end
```

Perhaps Order should also contain "belongs_to :customer"?

Here are the relevant parts of the schema file for reference:

```
create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "fname"
  t.string   "middle_initial"
  t.string   "lname"
  t.string   "street_add"
  t.string   "city"
  t.string   "state"
  t.string   "zipcode"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "home_phone"
  t.string   "cell_phone"
  t.string   "phone_pref"
  t.string   "password"
  t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "barcode"
  t.text     "description"
  t.decimal  "selling_price",   precision: 5, scale: 2
  t.string   "unit_of_measure"
  t.integer  "qty_on_hand"
  t.integer  "location_aisle"
  t.string   "location_area"
  t.datetime "created_at",                              null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                              null: false
end

create_table "order_lines", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "qty_ordered"
  t.decimal  "unit_price",        precision: 5, scale: 2
  t.decimal  "total_price",       precision: 7, scale: 2
  t.integer  "order_id"
  t.integer  "item_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                                null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                                null: false
end

add_index "order_lines", ["item_id"], name: "index_order_lines_on_item_id"
add_index "order_lines", ["order_id"], name: "index_order_lines_on_order_id"

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "billing_street_add"
  t.string   "billing_city"
  t.string   "billing_state"
  t.string   "billing_zipcode"
  t.string   "shipping_street_address"
  t.string   "shipping_city"
  t.string   "shipping_state"
  t.string   "shipping_zipcode"
  t.string   "cc_fname"
  t.string   "cc_middle_initial"
  t.string   "cc_lname"
  t.string   "cc_number"
  t.string   "cc_security_code"
  t.string   "cc_exp_month"
  t.string   "cc_exp_year"
  t.decimal  "subtotal",                precision: 7,  scale: 2
  t.integer  "tax_percent"
  t.decimal  "shipping_fee",            precision: 5,  scale: 2
  t.decimal  "total",                   precision: 20, scale: 2
  t.integer  "customer_id"
  t.integer  "order_line_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                                       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                                       null: false
end

add_index "orders", ["customer_id"], name: "index_orders_on_customer_id"
add_index "orders", ["order_line_id"], name: "index_orders_on_order_line_id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your current schema.

> Perhaps Order should also contain "belongs_to :customer"?

Yes, that could come in handy. You could just add it whenever you feel like you need it.

edit:

```
    t.decimal  "unit_price",        precision: 5, scale: 2
    t.decimal  "total_price",       precision: 7, scale: 2
```

Why do you need to save the prices in OrderLines? You already have the item prices in your Item model.